# React environment variables error 'Unexpected token' in firebase config

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm running a react project with a backend in firebase and I'm trying to setup a .env file for the configuration settings.

When I run 'npm start', I get a parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," after the word 'process' inside the 'const firebaseConfig' settings.

[image]

Here are the pertinent files:

**firebase-config.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: {process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY} //error occurs at the dot '.' after the word 'process'
    authDomain: {process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN}
    projectId: {process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID}
    storageBucket: {process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET}
    messagingSenderId: {process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}
    appId: {process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID}
    measurementId: {process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID}

};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app)
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**.env (in the root folder)**

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
REACT_APP_PROJECTID="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
REACT_APP_APP_ID="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID="<the actual firebase config settings here>"
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react_tut",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^3.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript's ES6 syntax lets you do this:

```js
const a = 4;
const x = { z: { a } };
```

but not this:

```js
const a = { b: 4 };
const x = { z: { a.b } };
```

To get it to work, do

```js
const a = { b: 4 };
const x = { z: { b: a.b } };
```

Solution (stuff should not be in curly brackets):

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID

};
```

Comment: so how would you correct my file?

Comment: I added it in the answer.

Comment: Reload your page

Comment: I was following a tutorial and they did it that way...wonder how they got their program to work with the curly braces?  Anyway, thanks a lot.  I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal I think Sean meant reload this SO page so I can see his edited answer.